# Matching and sorting data in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, sorting, matching

I have a list of bacteria each with it's own abundance in a dataframe. I also have the same list of bacteria but in a different order in the same dataframe.

I want to match the abundances to this second list but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

**dyplyr** contains several methods for sorting data but I don't know how to match the abundance and print it into a new column so it now matches with the second list of bacteria.

Here's the beginning of my dataset:

```
Taxon                              Total_abundance            Tips  
Acaricomes phytoseiuli             0.000382414        Methanothermobacter thermautotrophicus
Acetivibrio cellulolyticus         0.013979274        Methanobacterium beijingense
Acetobacter aceti                  0.181150551        Methanobacterium bryantii
Acetobacter estunensis             0.023074895        Methanosarcina mazei
Acetobacter tropicalis             0.014615221        Persephonella marina
Achromobacter piechaudii           0.031811039        Sulfurihydrogenibium azorense
Achromobacter xylosoxidans         0.041558442        Balnearium lithotrophicum
Acidicapsa borealis                0.035525932        Isosphaera pallida
Acidimicrobium ferrooxidans        0.013841209        Simkania negevensis
Acidiphilium angustum              0.041702984        Parachlamydia acanthamoebae
Acidiphilium cryptum               0.039265944        Leptospira biflexa
Acidiphilium rubrum                0.041702984        Leptospira fainei
...
```

So, the abundance matches the data in Taxon column, and I want the abundance to also be matched with the bacteria in the "Tips" column.

For example, Acaricomes phytoseiuli has an abundance of 0.000382414, so in column D 0.000382414 will be printed next to where Acaricomes phytoseiuli is located. Again, Taxon and Tips contains exactly the same data, just in a different order.

I hope that makes sense.

It doesn't matter if this is done in R or Excel, thanks.

Comment: Where do the bacteria names repeat?

Comment: Please provide a data example which actually contains matches.

Comment: @PLATANIUM Well the list is over 1000 long, this is just the top part, The Taxon column is in alphabetical order and the abundance matches this, the Tips column is in the order of a phylogenetic tree, and I need to match the abundances here too. Taxon and Tips are identical aside from the order they are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's hard to test without some data that matches, but something like this should work, using `match` to match up values.

```
df$D <- df$Total_abundance[ match( df$Tips, df$Taxon ) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your list of bacteria is unique
as a sample data frame:

```
dff <- data.frame(bacteria1=letters[1:10], abundance1=runif(10,0,1),
                  bacteri2=sample(letters[1:10],10), abundance2=0)
```

now we will find the bacteria rows and insert the abundances:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dff)){
  s <- which(dff$bacteri2[i]==dff$bacteria1)
  dff$abundance2[i] <- dff$abundance1[s]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In excel under column D  you can do the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(C3;A3:B13;2;FALSE)
```

**C3** would be the **TIP** and **A3:B13** the range where it searches for this, **A** being the **bacteria name** and **B** the **abundance** and if found will return the corresponding abundance of the match.

If you get an error like `#N/A` than there is no match. You can also avoid these errors by using this formula:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3;$A$3:B13;2;FALSE);"No match")
```

**Edit**: Adjust the ranges to your file!

**Edit 2**: Keep in mind the seperator I use is `;` and your excel might use the comma `,` seperator

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your Taxon and Tips columns contain exactly the same data, only in different order, they have no place being together in the same data frame. You should either have two data frames, or come up with some sort of key to define the place of a Taxon item in the phylogenetic tree and then re-sort the data frame as needed, either in alphabetic order or by phylogeny.
As a quick solution, I would first extract the Tips column in a separate data frame, join it with the original data frame by the Tips and Taxon columns, thus obtaining the correct order of abundance values in the new data frame and (if you still insist) using cbind to glue the newly re-sorted abundance column back into the original data frame. Like so, assuming you're using dplyr (df is a dummy stand-in for your data set):

```
df <- data.frame(Taxon=c("a","b","c","d","e"), Abundance=c(1:5), Tips=c("b","a","d","c","e"))
new_df <- select(df, Tips)
new_df <- left_join(new_df, df, by=c("Tips"= "Taxon"))
df <- cbind(df, New_Abund=new_df$Abundance)
rm(new_df)
```